# how to neglect a string in sentence using regular expression?

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I have a large number of questions, in this form:

```
Q. 1. If you are given a dry piece of land for cultivation what will you do before
sowing the seeds?
Q. 2. During which months do farmers grow mustard in India?
```

I want to neglect the (Q. 1.,Q. 2......so on ) from these questions. I am using this regex to do so:

```
`/(Q..+[^(A)]+)/`
```

But this regex selects all the words in the sentence.
How can I fix this?

Comment: You're not being clear. What's the input and output required?

Comment: i want this output from above input of quetion 1 as   (If you are given a dry piece of land for cultivation what will you do before sowing the seeds?)

Comment: Hello @SurajRajput, I've edited your question. I believe it is more clear this way. If you disagree with the edit, you can roll it back. To roll it back, click on the "edited ... ago" and look for the "rollback" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex which uses look aheads and behinds

```
/(?<=Q\. \d+\.).*?(?=(Q\. \d+\.|$))/gs
```

It will just match the question without any groups.

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/sU9aY4/1) Note: If you don't have `s` flag support, then you can replace `.*?` with `[\s\S]*?`

If you've any difficulty in using the regex due to various flavors and their drawabacks, you could use the regex `Q\.\s+\d+\.\s*(.*)` which has already been suggested in pne of the answers and use the group 1.

Comment: @MousamiRoul matter of adding a `+` Edited

Comment: @AmitJoki: In the PCRE flavor, `\d+` won't work in a lookbehind.  It won't work in NSRegularExpression (Objective-C/Apple flavor) either.  And JavaScript, the only flavor that doesn't support "s" mode, also doesn't support lookbehinds.  Are you sure you wouldn't rather suggest something involving capturing groups?

Comment: @AlanMoore Included one which involves groups. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Q\.\s+\d+\.\s*(.*)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/57

Comment: i want to neglect  Q. 1. and Q. 2. from questions i not want to select all

Comment: @SurajRajput when you capture group 1 `Q1` will be neglected

Answer (score 0):

```
`/Q\. [0-9]+\. (.+)/g`
```

Will match the question and ignore the numbering.